# Webpack SCSS and autoprefixer do not work together

Tags: compilation, sass, webpack, autoprefixer

Having the following webpack configuration for assets compiling I can't get autoprefixer to work. The extracted css does not get the needed prefixes.

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
    precss       = require('precss'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'),
    path = require('path');



const sassLoaders = [
    'css-loader!autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 2 version',
    'postcss-loader',
    'sass-loader?indentedSyntax=sass&includePaths[]=' + path.resolve(__dirname, '.')
]

const config = {
    entry: {
        //nsb: ['./js/nsb']
        dashboard: ['./js/dashboard']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.sass$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', sassLoaders.join('!'))
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
            },
            {
                test:   /\.docs\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader?pack=cleaner"
            },
            {
                test:   /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader"
            },

            { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
        ]
    },
    postcss: function () {
        return {
            defaults: [precss, autoprefixer],
            cleaner:  [autoprefixer({ browsers: [] })]
        };
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, './build'),
        publicPath: '/bundles/dashboard/build/'
    },
    amd: {jQuery: true},
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.js', Infinity)
    ],
    /* postcss: [
        autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions']
        })
    ],
    */
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            jquery: 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            magnificPopup: 'node_modules/maginific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js' //JQuery Plugin
        },

        modulesDirectories: ['./js', 'node_modules'],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.sass'],
        root: [path.join(__dirname, './')]
    }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846209/webpack-with-less-and-postcss-autoprefixer/47849353#47849353 Maybe it helps...

Answer (score 0):

The `css-loader` comes with it's own autoprefixer config you will need to disable this in order for your config to work. So wherever you have `css-loader` you need to do add to disable the `css-loader` autoprefixer.

`css-loader?-autoprefixer`

More info can found [here](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader/issues/37#issuecomment-167095305) & [here](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#minification)

So your config will look like this

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
  precss       = require('precss'),
  autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
  ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'),
  path = require('path');



const sassLoaders = [
  'css-loader?-autoprefixer!autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 2 version',
  'postcss-loader',
  'sass-loader?indentedSyntax=sass&includePaths[]=' + path.resolve(__dirname, '.')
]

const config = {
  entry: {
    //nsb: ['./js/nsb']
    dashboard: ['./js/dashboard']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', sassLoaders.join('!'))
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
      },
      {
        test:   /\.docs\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader?-autoprefixer!postcss-loader?pack=cleaner"
      },
      {
        test:   /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader?-autoprefixer!postcss-loader"
      },

      { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
    ]
  },
  postcss: function () {
    return {
      defaults: [precss, autoprefixer],
      cleaner:  [autoprefixer({ browsers: [] })]
    };
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, './build'),
    publicPath: '/bundles/dashboard/build/'
  },
  amd: {jQuery: true},
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.js', Infinity)
  ],
  /* postcss: [
    autoprefixer({
    browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    })
    ],
    */
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      jquery: 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      magnificPopup: 'node_modules/maginific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js' //JQuery Plugin
    },

    modulesDirectories: ['./js', 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.sass'],
    root: [path.join(__dirname, './')]
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Also, I think you can remove the `autoprefixer-loader` that you have inside your `sassLoaders` since you are using PostCSS with autoprefixer.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I just tried out suggested but the autoprefixer still not work, just checking compiled for example `display: flex;` remains the same

Comment: Do you have this code somewhere so I can have a look at it?

Comment: BTW, your browsers settings in the `autoprefixer` loader inside the `sassLoaders` array is missing an "s" it's `last 2 versions` not `last 2 version`

Comment: making the corrections still not work. Just to ask did you tried yourself ? maybe is working in your case and I miss something else

Comment: I can't try without having an idea of how your code/folder structure looks like. So if you can do this, I can then try and test it.

Comment: thanks I got it and is working now https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader/issues/42

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code, notice the addition of "?-autoprefixer" between css-loader and postcss-loader.

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
precss       = require('precss'),
autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'),
path = require('path');
const sassLoaders = [
'css-loader!autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 2 version',
'postcss-loader',
'sass-loader?indentedSyntax=sass&includePaths[]=' + path.resolve(__dirname, 
'.')
]

const config = {
entry: {
    //nsb: ['./js/nsb']
    dashboard: ['./js/dashboard']
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.sass$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', sassLoaders.join('!'))
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
        },
        {
            test:   /\.docs\.css$/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader?-autoprefixer!postcss-loader?pack=cleaner"
        },
        {
            test:   /\.css$/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader?-autoprefixer!postcss-loader"
        },

        { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
        { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
    ]
},
postcss: function () {
    return {
        defaults: [precss, autoprefixer],
        cleaner:  [autoprefixer({ browsers: [] })]
    };
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, './build'),
    publicPath: '/bundles/dashboard/build/'
},
amd: {jQuery: true},
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.js', Infinity)
],
/* postcss: [
    autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    })
],
*/
resolve: {
    alias: {
        jquery: 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        magnificPopup: 'node_modules/maginific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js' //JQuery Plugin
    },

    modulesDirectories: ['./js', 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.sass'],
    root: [path.join(__dirname, './')]
}
}

module.exports = config;
```

One more note: In my project's root directory I also have a postcss.config.js with the following content:

```
module.exports = {
parser: 'postcss-scss',
plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer'),
]
}
```